# How to fix linker error "Undefined symbols" in code for assignment?

Tags: c

Sorry to bother with this small issue for some but I am having trouble with calling the insertionsort function.

The professor said that the return value is either going to be just 0 or 1. 1 for success and 0 for failure. I just have to sort the linked list with tokens from the file. I am just doing a test of how I can implement this function because this function is the most important thing for the project.

This is what the professor is going to run and wants to see. `-I` for insertionsort and `-q` for quicksort during compile time:

`./fileSort -i ./somefile`

If "./somefile" contains:

> hi,there, every, one

then output should be:

`every hi one there`

So I need to call two functions:

```
int insertionsort(void *toSort, int (*cmp)(void*, void*));
int quicksort(void *toSort, int (*cmp)(void*, void*));
```

but so far I am trying to get one done and I am very frustrated. Any help will be great.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFSIZE 8

int compare(void *, void *);
void toSort(char *, int,  int (*cmp)(void*, void*));
void swap(char *, char *);
void print_array (char **, int );

// int insertionsort(void *toSort, int (*comparator)(void*, void*));


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    int insertionsort(void *toSort, int (*cmp)(void*, void*));
    //build an array
    char *array[BUFSIZE] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "\0"};

    int n = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
    if(n == -1)
    {
        printf("Error getting the size of the array\n");
    }

    printf("Size of the array: %d\n", n);

    printf("Sorting the array.\n");
    insertionsort(toSort, compare);
    print_array(array, n);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}

int compare( void * a,  void * b) 
{
   int val1 = *(int*)a;
   int val2 = *(int*)b;

   return ( val1 - val2 ); 
}

void toSort(char *array, int size, int (*cmp)(void*, void*))
{
    int i, j;
    for ( i = 1; i < size; i++ )
    {
        j = i;
        while ( j > 0 && cmp( (char*)array+j-1, (char*)array+j ) > 0 )
                      // ^^^ call of cmp instead of operator >
        {
            swap( (char*)array+j-1, (char*)array+j);
            j--;
        }
    }
}

void swap(char *a, char *b)
{
    char *temp;
    temp = a;
  a = b;
    b = temp;
}

void print_array (char **array, int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf ("%d: %s\n", i, array[i]);
    }
}
```

This is causing a compile error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:                                         
  "_insertionsort", referenced from:                                               
      _main in funcPointer-3f472a.o                                                
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64                                    
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: "I am having trouble". Please tell us exactly what trouble you are having. A compile error? A runtime error? Something else? Please provide exact error messages or debug output.

Comment: Where do you expect the `insertionsort` function to come from? That is not a standard C function so you need to write it or have some code somewhere for it.

Comment: Well this is what my professor wants : int insertionsort(void *toSort, int (*cmp)(void*, void*)); one for insertionsort and one for Quicksort. Maybe I am confused or  something is wrong here.  And I am actually just doing this as a test. I have to implement this function on a linked list with tokens from a file. I have been spending non stop time on this project and I am so frustrated. Any resource will help

Comment: That looks like the prof has given you the function signature. You still need to implement it.

Comment: I think this question has some general value. If there is not already such a question it might be something more students with similar assignments might find useful. Obviously proposing duplicates is the right thing now - if you know one.

Comment: Note that comparator functions should not modify what their arguments point at.  You should use pointers to constant data — `int (*cmp)(const void *v1, const void *v2)` or thereabouts — for the comparators.

Comment: `insertionsort(toSort, compare);` is a mistake (although it's not clear to me from what's posted what the intent is)

Comment: The signature of the standard C [`qsort`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.5.2) function is `void qsort(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));`.  If you are sorting arbitrary data types, then the information you need is the base address of the array, the number of elements in the array, the size of each element, and a comparator function to compare two elements of the array. **All** those are necessary. Sadly, your `insertionsort()` function is missing both sizes — it cannot be used to sort an arbitrary size of array of an arbitrary type.

Comment: It's puzzling that you mention _"I just have to sort the linked list with tokens from the file"_ but there's no sign of a linked list in the code.  There's no sign of code to read tokens, either.  Maybe you should start with the code to read the data from the file.  Then it may be easier to see how to move on from there.  Your 'integer comparison' function isn't going to be much help for comparing strings — you'll have to rewrite that, too.  If you're not going to handle arrays of arbitrary sizes and arbitrary types, then using a comparator with `void *` is overkill.

Comment: No this was just a test to implement this function and then move on to creating a linked list of tokens from a file for integers and strings. And I can not seem to even pass from this test. But I am trying

Comment: regarding your statement: `This is causing a compile error:`  No, this is a linker error

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`,at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same thing

Comment: regarding: `int main(int argc, char const *argv[])`  Since those parameters are not used in your code, the compiler will output two warning messages about unused parameters.  To correct that, suggest using the other signature for `main()`  I.E.  `int main( void )`

Comment: This is a major problem in the posted code:  *untitled1.c:23:9: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘void (*)(char *, int,  int (*)(void *, void *))’*  for this statement: `insertionsort(toSort, compare);`

Comment: in general, function prototypes should be before any functions, not buried within some function.  Therefore this: `int insertionsort(void *toSort, int (*cmp)(void*, void*));` should be before the function: `main()`

Comment: there is no function `insertionsort()` in the C library, so your code must actually contain that function.  The posted code does not contain that function.   Suggest writing the function: `insertionsort()`  into your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is a linker error telling you that during build there was no implementation found for the function you are trying to call.
The fact that the prototype is seen directly in the shown code (and some other hints) make me assume that it is you who is supposed to actually implement that function.

So, to solve the error you have quoted you can simply include the following at the place where you have a comment which shows the prototype for the missing function:

```
// prototype, to tell the compiler about the existence of this function
int insertionsort(void *toSort, int (*comparator)(void*, void*));

// implementation of that function
// (the separation is not really needed but a recommended practice,
// to prepare for later work with multiple code files
int insertionsort(void *toSort, int (*comparator)(void*, void*))
{
    /* empty, the point of this code is only to get rid of the linker error,
       to be filled in by you, implementation according to what you learned
       in class about sorting
     */

    return 0; // to match the prototype with return value int
    /* find out about this return value,
       i.e. how the function is supposed to be used and what it should return
     */

}
```

Comment: The professor said that the return value is either going to be just 0 or 1. 1 for success and 0 for failure. I just have to sort the linked list with tokens from the file. I am just doing a test of how I can implement this function because this function is the most important thing for the project.

Comment: Ah, then the 0 I chose happens to be correct for the code I wrote inside, i.e. no code, no chance to find. So you can actually try calling this code as intended by the professor. It will always fail to sort...

Comment: Amir, can I make my answer more helpful to you? (Without actually writing the sorting implementation that is.)

Comment: ./fileSort -i ./somefile
  If "./somefile" contains: hi,there, every,     one
  output should be:
  every
  hi
  one
         there
This is what the professor going to run and wants to see. -I for insertionsort and -q for quicksort during compile time.

Comment: I dont need answer I need a route to follow to learn. I will be greatful

Comment: Sure, that is exactly what I wrote this answer for. So what more help do you need with it?

Comment: Do you know any resource I can read to work with system call for open and read to take in tokens from a file and store it in a linked list. That would be very helpful.

Comment: Frankly, I propose the textbook for the class you are attending. It is probably written precisely for the purpose of providing exactly the information you need right now.

Comment: There is no text book provided to us. We were given two pdf files which I went through it and nothing I found nothing that I need to learn right now. I am falling in love with c but with this frustration I am feeling like I can't do it. I have spent so much time and I still can not get the tokens from the file. We can not use any f-calls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208468/discussion-between-amir-and-yunnosch).

Comment: Other useful thinkgs on the route: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/ to get going, i.e. start with early easy things and then build up. Once you did implement something and it does not work https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ If you did not get any textbook, then please start with basic tutorials, follow them until they work, then  edit them to see what happens.

Comment: Great source of info found here, in the info collected by StackOverflow community on the topic of "C". It includes a list of books. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208472/discussion-between-amir-and-yunnosch).

Comment: void *toSort is being called in insertionsort function. What does this represent? I am little confused and can't find any resource on how this is even legal in c.

Comment: I am not aware of a non-empty implementation of `insertionsort()`. What exactly are you referring to?

Comment: I have made the insertionsort function. Can you help me with that please?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. I propose to create a new question which focuses on the new help you need with that.